Mockito MockedStatic Object, pass as an argument to class
Unable to pass type MockedStatic object into method/ constructor
I have this legacy code -
class Mom {
   Mom(Class StaticBaby){
   }
}

I've used Mockito's mockstatic (v5.12) to mock out StaticBaby like
MockedStatic<StaticBaby> mockedStaticBaby = Mockito.mockStatic(StaticBaby.class)

However when I pass mockedStaticBaby to constructor Mom() I get java.lang.ClassCastException
Is writing a wrapper around dependency StaticBaby my only option?
Trying to migrate from Powermock (which supported passing around a static mock into a method) to Mockito, hence the gymnastics and cleanup.

In your Mom class constructor StaticBaby is just a variable name. It has nothing to do with StaticBaby class

Class.class != StaticBaby.class.
